# How to display the first and last record from a collection?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

```
[
{
    "EmpId" : 1,
    "EmpFname" : "Karan",
    "EmpLname" : "mehta",
    "Department" : "HR",
    Salary : 300000
},
{
    "EmpId" : 2,
    "EmpFname" : "Rohit",
    "EmpLname" : "Sharma",
    "Department" : "Admin",
    Salary : 75000
},
{
    "EmpId" : 3,
    "EmpFname" :"Ankush",
    "EmpLname" :"Rajput",
    "Department" :"Account",
    "Salary" : 60000
},
{
    EmpId : 4,
    EmpFname :Priyadershini,
    EmpLname :Sharma,
    Department : HR,
    Salary : 500000
},
]
```

The above collection is the employee details.In this collection to display the first and last employee details.Is it possible for using a single query. I did many ways but i can't get the answer

Comment: First and last according to what, `EmpId`? This is doable with `$sort`, `$limit`, and `$unionWith`, but you need to state what ordering you are using

Comment: Don't use any order just display the first inserted and last inserted document in a collection

Comment: I would suggest picking a field to order on. You can use the `$natural` operator, but the [documentation notes some caveats](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-in-natural-order). Perhaps add a `createdAt` field with a timestamp. At the very least consider using `_id` since the ObjectIds that are used by default include a timestamp component.

Answer (score 1):

As @user20042973 commented, you need to clarify what ordering you are using for "first" / "last".

Generally, you can do something like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  // first record
  {
    $sort: {
      Salary: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $sort: {
            Salary: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RPadsEgCAc7)